# How can I delete files in the remote repository?

Tags: git, github

I am not sure what is the exact term for this problem. Basically, I need to remove some files & directory on my remote repository

I have a local Git repository and remote repository on GitHub

1. Had been working myself.
2. A friend made a pull request.
3. I merged his request (via the GitHub interface)
4. I pulled the changes.
5. I tested the code and decided not to take his changes (shouldn't have merged at the first place)
6. I reverted back to a previous commit
7. Made some changes
8. Push to the server.

This is how my local repository looks like at the moment:

```
*   7e143b1  (HEAD)
|\
| *   18cea0f  (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
| |\
| | * fc19ccf
* | | 6f3c58a
|/ /
* | 8d82486
|/
| * d3ce65f  (pre-install-activeadmin)
|/
* 7d0566c
* d1c77ab
* 75ba704
* 30dc67c  (heroku/master)
* f89b1f6
* ea5e2db
* 08931d6
* 9773a6f
* b636aba
* cb6f8d4
```

I can change my local repo to `7d0566c`. I am not sure where the head on my remote repository is pointing to.

How do I remove those files that are on remote repo but are not on my local repository?

Obviously, I do not see any of his files in my local repo because I did a reset of my *HEAD* to a previous commit. However, the remote repo still shows his files. When I commit, it commits just fine.

Is my workflow wrong? I should have just tested the patch at the first place.

Comment: You don't add/remove files on a remote such as github since it is a bare repository. See if the refspecs for github and your local repo are the same by executing `git rev-parse HEAD` and `git rev-parse origin/master` (if your remote is named `origin`).

Comment: I think it will help if you show the output of `git log --pretty="format:%h %d" --graph --all` and explain from there.

Comment: Right. you don't add/ remove files. Ahem. They are different. How should I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: *   7e143b1  (HEAD)
|\  
| *   18cea0f  (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
| |\  
| | * fc19ccf 
* | | 6f3c58a 
|/ /  
* | 8d82486 
|/  
| * d3ce65f  (pre-install-activeadmin)
|/  
* 7d0566c 
* d1c77ab 
* 75ba704 
* 30dc67c  (heroku/master)
* f89b1f6 
* ea5e2db 
* 08931d6 
* 9773a6f 
* b636aba 
* cb6f8d4 

Not sure how this would help. I can change my local repo to 7d0566c.    I am not sure where the head on my remote repo is pointing to

Comment: I'm curious about `7e143b1`. Is this where you did your revert? If yes, how did you do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*Pull the changes from the server*, then do a `git rm` on your local repo, commit the changes, and push to the server. The files will be deleted.

Comment: is there an easy way to remove these files from my local repo? say there are hundred of files? Thanks

Comment: @limaoit: I'm not a Git expert, so there's probably a better way, but a simple one would be to copy the directory somewhere else, pull from the server so it's up-to-date, then delete everything in the repo except `.git`, move everything (except `.git`) from your backup to your repo, commit, and push.

Comment: You can use the shell to remove the files.  That means you can use a shell script, find, file globbing, or whatever mass removal technique you want.  When you're done, run "git add -A ." from the top level directory.  The -A flag will tell git to notice files that you've removed.

Comment: I figured that you actually need to use 'git rm' to remove files from the tree and from file system. 'rm' alone is not enough.

Comment: @dvliman yes, you would need to do 'git rm', but @wadesworld 's point is that you can still use the command line for that.  for instance:  `git rm junk/*.java` would `git rm` all of the java files under the junk directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `18cea0f` is where your pull request merge happened. In order to revert that merge, you can do:

```
git revert -m 1 18cea0f
```

You can read more here: http://progit.org/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html

Comment: I have done that. My local repo is reverted successfully. There is no problem there. The remote repo is the one that causes problem. It contains files from fc19ccf .etc...

Comment: @limanoit You just need to push your changes to the remote repo: `git push origin master`.

Comment: @htnata Yes I did that. That is why I asked this question. My local repo does not contain, say file A, B, C. But my remote repo contains file A, B, C which is the effect of previous merging. 

I actually fixed this problem by recloning the repo. Manually delete the file. and push the commit. This is quite hacky. Wondering if there is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: @limanoit If you do a fresh clone and do the `git revert ...` as in my answer, and then push it, you should get the same result as what you did. I think this is what happened. You used `git reset --hard` and you then committed some changes on top of that (step 7). You tried to push, but you weren't be able to push. Then you did `git pull`, which merged the pull request from remote with your master. That explains why you still have the pull request.