# Remove files from a remote branch in Git

Tags: git

I accidentally pushed some files to my remote Git branch. What is the best way to remove those particular files from the remote branch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pull the changes from remote, do a `git rm` on your local repository, commit the changes, and again push to the remote. The files will be deleted.

You can check this earlier question on Stack Overflow:
*[How can I delete files in the remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539338/how-can-i-delete-files-in-the-remote-repository)*

Comment: Can u give more details ? Why need to pull from remote, I'm the only one who is using this branch

Comment: I assumed that the changes present in remote repo are not in your local checked out copy. If its already there then you can delete the files using git rm <filename> command and then push changes.

Comment: but i need to keep this in my local, because i have pushed a config file to remote branch

Comment: In that case can you checkout on a new location (directory). Remove the files and commit. After that do a 'git pull' on your original directory. The deleted files will stay as uncommitted change.

Answer (score 24):

Since you do not want to push those files to the remote server, but want to keep the copies locally, your best bet is to do `git rm` with a `--cached` flag.

Basically, do this:

```
git rm --cached some/filename.ext
git rm --cached -r some/directory/
```

and then commit and push your changes back using

```
git commit -m "removing redundant files"
```

From the manpage for [`git rm`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html):

> --cached
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.